# Silverstripe: Adding to the translation tables

Tags: internationalization, silverstripe

I need to add additional translations to the Silverstripe 3 translation tables in sapphire/lang/[lang].yml

I am pulling in 'sapphire' as an SVN external so cannot just add the new values to the existing yml files.

Am I able to create additional language yml files for languages to add to these translations in mysite directory?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just create a new module with the following structure:

```
z_translations/
    _config.php
    lang/
        en.yml
```

The `z_` prefix ensures it comes alphabetically last, currently there's no way to influence loading order. the `translations` part can be anything. `_config.php` can be empty, but needs to be present for the folder to be detected as a module.

Note that in order to override translations in `framework/admin/lang/`, you have to create an `admin` subfolder in your module as well ... don't ask ;)